# SQL Server stored procedure syntax explanation

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName> 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT <@Param1, sysname, @p1>, <@Param2, sysname, @p2>
END
GO
```

Can anyone help me understand the syntax of SQL? I am new to this forum as well as in SQL Server. I would like to know about the GO command in stored procedure at the end of script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `GO` is **not** a SQL command that you can use inside a stored procedure - it's a *batch delimiter* in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL
>   Server utilities.

Also note that GO is not a TSQL statement.

> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.

Its a batch seperator used in SQL Server Management Studio. You can go to **Tools--> Options--> Query Execution**

[image]